# Terms to apply to something that leaves strong memory

Tags: meaning, word-choice, adjectives, synonyms, connotation

Do the following terms have positive, neutral or negative meaning?

- *memorable*
- *impressive*
- *remarkable*

What are other similar terms that are used for positive, neutral and negative intention?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the terms mentioned so far (memorable, impressive, remarkable, unforgettable, etc.) tend to have positive connotations in the absence of any negative modifier. *Memorable* is the most neutral of the bunch.

For equivalents to *memorable* that have a negative connotation, you may have to go a little further afield. *Traumatic*, *notorious* and *infamous* can all mean "memorable in a bad way."

Comment: egregious, shocking

Answer (score 3):

*Impressive* has a clear positive meaning (“evoking admiration”, says the *New Oxford American Dictionary*). *Memorable* and *remarkable* are both supposedly neutral, and can be combined with negative events (e.g., “a memorable death”). For some reasons, I myself find *remarkable* as having a slightly positive tone that *memorable* doesn't have; others might comment in other answers or comments.

Comment: I think that memorable and remarkable are normally positive (for example one could exclaim "Remarkable!", and it would be generally viewed as a positive statement, even if the people who heard didn't know the context) except when they are applied to events with negative connotations.

Answer (score 1):

There is always *unforgettable*, which is neutral, and *momentous*, which is usually positive. Depending on the context you might also say *lasting*, *noteworthy* or *historic*.

Comment: I would have said *unforgettable* was usually positive, in the absence of explicit qualification...

Answer (score 1):

Leaving a lasting mark/impression is more than a word, but also should be there

Answer (score 1):

Most words here have slightly (or clearly) positive connotations. For one with a clearly negative one, try **devastating**.

Answer (score 1):

- never-to-be-forgotten
- ineffaceable
- indelible, indissoluble, un-removable, irrevocable, undying, imperishable
- prominent, striking, shocking, incredible, glaring
- long-standing, durable, life-long, live-long, relenting, lingering, evergreen